# Three.js - Create 3D text that's unaffected by zooming and panning

Tags: javascript, three.js

Three.js version: **r79**

Basically, I want to have a 3D object (a **mesh** created with **THREE.TextGeometry**) act like it's in 2D space but is always in the same exact place on the screen (never moves with the camera, no matter if I zoom or pan). Is there a way to do this?

I'm actually not quite sure how unless I make what I feel is a giant hack and update the coordinates of the text mesh every time there is a mouse scroll event or pan event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to add the mesh as a child of the camera.

```
scene.add( camera ); // required, since the camera has a child
camera.add( mesh );
mesh.position.set( 0, 0, - 100 ); // or whatever
```

three.js r.79

Comment: Does the camera type matter? I'm using THREE.PerspectiveCamera.

Comment: Yes. This approach likely will only work with perspective camera.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work with the perspective camera. Is there a similar website to jsfiddle that you know of where I can upload an example? I don't want to use jsfiddle because they're using three.js r54, which is quite old now.

Comment: Or use a different approach: two render passes, with the 2nd render pass rendering your overlay over top of the main scene. See http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_sprites.html.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. I got it to work with the perspective camera here: http://jsfiddle.net/akmcv7Lh/71/. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in my code, but since I know this way works, I will accept this answer.